# Aggregate values in dictionary by key

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm quite new to Python and just started working with dictionaries. I have the following question:

Given the following dictionary:

```
{'Berlin': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 3.502},
'New York': {'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 8.406},
'Munich': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 1.388}, ... }
```

How could I sum the population over countries? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
country_to_population = {}
for city, data in dict.iteritems():
    country = data['Country']
    if country not in country_to_population:
        country_to_population[country] = 0
    country_to_population[country] += data['Population']
```

You iterate the main dictionary and add population to a new dictionary that maps a country to population.

If using Python 3, do `items()` instead of `iteritems()`.

Comment: @ yper. Thank you very much for your input. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your data by country like below:

```
from itertools import groupby

my_dict = {'Berlin': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 3.502}, 'New York': {'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 8.406}, 'Munich': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 1.388}}

population = {}

for k,v in groupby(sorted(my_dict.items()), key=lambda i:i[1]['Country']):
    population[k] = sum(item[1]['Population'] for item in list(v))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> population
{'Germany': 4.89, 'USA': 8.406}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go inside the dict iterating on the key:

```
dict = {'Berlin': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 3502},
'New York': {'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 8406},
'Munich': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 1388}}
country = []
sum = {}
for key in dict:
    coun = dict[key]['Country']
    if coun in country:
        pass
    else:
        country.append(dict[key]['Country'])
        sum[coun] = 0

    sum[coun] += dict[key]['Population']

for key in sum:
    print(key, sum[key])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultdict` from collections module, with `int` assigned to it in order to have a default value of `0` to each country you are about to sum.

The code looks like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

country_dict = {"Berlin":{"Country":"Germany","Population":3.502},"Munich":{"Country":"Germany","Population":1.388},"New York":{"Country":"USA","Population":8.406}}

sum_countries_dict = defaultdict(int)
for item in country_dict.values():
    sum_countries_dict[item['Country']] += item['Population']
```

And the result is:

```
>>> country_dict
{'Berlin': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 3.502}, 'New York': {'Country': 'USA', 'Population': 8.406}, 'Munich': {'Country': 'Germany', 'Population': 1.388}}
>>> sum_countries_dict
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'Germany': 4.89, 'USA': 8.406})
>>> sum_countries_dict['Germany']
4.89
>>> sum_countries_dict['USA']
8.406
```